# Cyclomatic complexity of C# Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, cyclomatic-complexity

As per [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity):

> Cyclomatic complexity is a software metric, used to indicate the
>   complexity of a program. It is a quantitative measure of the number of
>   linearly independent paths through a program's source code. It was
>   developed by Thomas J. McCabe, Sr. in 1976.

Could this term apply to C# Linq with a lambda expression like this one:

```
_fred = fred.Where(c =>
    c.IsActive &&
    c.PriorityOrder.HasValue &&
(c.PriorityOrder == 0 || !(c.MinUnits == 0 && (!c.MaxUnits.HasValue || c.MaxUnits == 0))))
.GroupBy(x => x.Scope)
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

if so, what is the `cyclomatic complexity` of this bit of code and why does Resharper tells me it is.. **1**?

Same piece of logic from the `Where` clause above broken down into multiple `if` statements shows cyclomatic complexity of **9**. Why?

```
private IEnumerable<Priority> FilterPriorities(IEnumerable<Priority> priorities)
{
    var result = new List<Priority>();

    foreach (var p in priorities)
    {
        if (p.IsActive == false) continue;

        if (p.PriorityOrder.HasValue == false) continue;

        if (p.PriorityOrder == 0)
        {
            result.Add(p);
            continue;
        }

        if ((p.MinUnits == 0 && (!p.MaxUnits.HasValue || p.MaxUnits == 0)) == false)
        {
            result.Add(p);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I see a single linear path through this code.  Why do you think it shouldn't be `1`?

Comment: there is no branching here so I'm not sure why you expect it to be more complex.

Comment: Yep, you have a condition, but there is no `else`, so there's only one path.

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity doesn't include different paths taken inside function-calls.

Comment: @Tsar The fact of the matter is that it _isn't_ broken down into multiple nested `for`loops with `if/else`.

Comment: it doesn't look through method implementation.@Tsar

Comment: `don't you think this Linq query broken down into multiple nested for loops ...` no, definitely not. Linq is a separate method, it will be pushed into stack before begin executed.

Comment: If you want to know the cyclomatic complexity of the inner function, make it into a separate method and have ReSharper check that: `static bool MyClause(SomeType c) { return 
    c.IsActive &&
    c.PriorityOrder.HasValue &&
(c.PriorityOrder == 0 || !(c.MinUnits == 0 && (!c.MaxUnits.HasValue || c.MaxUnits == 0))); }`

Answer (score 2):

Cyclomatic complexity is not going to catch your LINQ expression as anything but a "simple" expression because that's what Cyclomatic complexity is defined to do.

If your expression can be understood/rewritten to be like this:

```
if (something)
    your_variable = this_thing;
else
    your_variable = this_other_thing;
```

then *that's* going to impact your cyclomatic complexity.

However, with LINQ, and most constructs using lambdas (which LINQ expressions are basically a syntax for creating), the compiler, and cyclomatic complexity analyzer, is going to see this:

```
your_variable = really_complex_expression;
```

So it's going to count that as 1 path through your code.

---

Whether or not we're going to need a different way of measuring complexity to handle this kind of thing is unknown (to me), but cyclomatic complexity is not it.